How to tell apart calcium hydroxide and calcium carbonate?
I'm exploring the curing time of whitewash and or lime mortar. Both are the same, $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ turning into $\ce{CaCO3}$, however I couldn't find some straight answers in regards to their curing (carbonation) time. Some claim days, others weeks.  I am trying to measure how long it takes the carbonation process of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$. I want to at least qualitatively asses if there is any $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ left.
I'd like to know if there's any reactant that would react with one and not with the other ($\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ and $\ce{CaCO3}$).
I'd appreciate any help pointing me to references of this process in general!

One way, even roughly quantitative, is reaction with acids. Carbonate would form carbon dioxide, hydroxide would not.
$$\ce{Ca(OH)2(s) + 2 HCl(aq) -> CaCl2(aq) + H2O(l)}$$
$$\ce{CaCO3(s) + 2 HCl(aq) -> CaCl2(aq) + H2O(l) + CO2(g)}$$
You can compare the weight of the tested sample and volume of evolved $\ce{CO2}$
$\pu{1 g}\ \ce{CaCO3}$ would create about 244 mL $\ce{CO2}$, but part would dissolve in the acid.

I'm guessing the bubbling would be obvious. So I could add a few drops to a surface containing the mix of Ca(OH)2 and CaCO3 and look for bubbling, right?

Dropping acid on solid hydroxide could lead to boiling of acid. It may not be the best idea.

Your question is complex. the solubility of calcium carbonate in water is about 1mg in 100 ml of [CO2 free] water. the solubility of calcium hydroxide in water is about 185 mg in 100mL of water. A careful preparation of the solid in water followed by centrifugation should give relatively pure CaCO3 and a saturated solution of CaCO3 in a dilute [almost] saturated solution of Ca[OH]2. The solution could be useful for nephelometric or conductimetric measurement of CO2 uptake. Precise analysis will take some care in weighing. I would consider using conductivity and pH as secondary methods. As usual a description of your experimental purposes would be helpful.

Ammonium chloride $\ce{NH4Cl}$ reacts easily with $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ according to $$\ce{2 NH4Cl + Ca(OH)2 -> CaCl2 + 2 NH3 + 2 H2O}$$ But $\ce{NH4Cl}$  does not react with $\ce{CaCO3}$.

Would it be possible to dissolve the Ammonium chloride in water and add a few drops to the surface containing the mix of Ca(OH)2 and CaCO3?

Why doing this trial ?

exploring the curing time of whitewash and or lime mortar. Both are the same, CaOH2 turning into CaCO3, however I couldnt find some straight answers in regards to their curing (carbonation) time. Some claim days, others weeks. I want to at least qualitatively asses if there is any CaOH2 left

Thermogravimetric analysis. Calcium hydroxide decomposes endothermically at 580°C, so a mass loss around that temperature would indicate the hydroxide and its magnitude may even be used for a quantitative estimate if you have a mixture.

TGA -thermogravimetry might be better

Got them confused, thanks.

Check pH and solubility:


The pH value of saturated solution of $\ce{CaCO3}$ in equilibrium with atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ is 8.35, while the pH of saturated solution in water at $\pu{20 °C}$ of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ is 12.6.

Calcium carbonate is practically insoluble in water ($\pu{0.013 g L^−1}$ at $\pu{25 °C}$), while calcium hydroxide is more soluble ($\pu{1.59 g L^−1}$ of saturated solution at $\pu{25 °C}$)



Reference:

Malešič, J., Kadivec, M., Kunaver, M. et al. Nano calcium carbonate versus nano calcium hydroxide in alcohols as a deacidification medium for lignocellulosic paper. Herit Sci 7, 50 (2019). DOI: 10.1186/s40494-019-0294-6


How easily do we forget actual chemistry! Long time ago, it was a classical test for a school demo to show that our breath contains carbon dioxide. Students would take filtered lime water ($\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ saturated water) and bubble breath with a straw. The solution became cloudy due to precipitated, $\ce{CaCO3}$ and by continuous breathing, the solution became clear $\ce{Ca(HCO3)2}$.
So your problem is not that trivial and question incomplete. If you are doing solution phase \ce{CO2}$ absorption, you will have three species. Suspended calcium hydroxide, soluble calcium hydroxide, and dissolved calcium bicarbonate. If you are doing solid phase sorption, that is another story.
Then you are asking the about time of complete carbonation of slaked lime, this is a kinetics problem...the rates will depend on countless variables which you do not describe or they are not in your control. In short, no simple analytical test exists, except thermogravimetry or eudiometry i.e., measurement of gas volumes. You acidify the product, and see how much carbon dioxide evolved. From the volume of the gas, one would measure the moles of carbonate present in the sample.
